# How To Create Social Application Tokens With Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, oauth-2.0, token

I'm Successfully With This Tutorial :
https://www.section.io/engineering-education/django-google-oauth/ 
In this tutorial, she's created how to login with google.
I Just Started To Learn Back End With Django, And i Want to send this data with django rest api.
My Friend is Front End and he need my user data. He said create the tokens.
Im Confused to create the tokens. And i see in the table there is a name "Social Application Tokens".
My Question is:
How To Create Social Application Tokens Automaticly when user login with Google?, And Whats the tools to create that ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use this as a guide anytime I want to implement social login with Django:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wlcCvzOLL8w&list=PLOLrQ9Pn6caw0PjVwymNc64NkUNbZlhFw&index=9

Hope this helps you